# Scrollable List with items of set pixel height in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to create a GUI in swing.  The GUI would hold a variable number of `JPanel`s of a fixed height stacked on top of one another.  When the total height of the `JPanel`s in the stack is greater than the height of enclosing frame, the user should be able to scroll up and down through the Panels.

```
         ____________________
        |                    |
        |   panel 1          |
        |                    |
        |____________________|
        |                    |
        |   panel 2          |
        |                    |
        |____________________|
     ___|____________________|___
    |   |   panel 3          |   |
    |   |                    |   |
    |   |____________________|   |     ^
    |   |                    |   |     |
    |   |   panel 4          |   |     |
    |   |                    |   |     |
    |   |____________________|   |     v
    |   |                    |   |
    |   |   panel 5          |   |
    |___|____________________|___|
        |____________________|
        |                    |
        |   panel 6          |
        |                    |
        |____________________|
```

I've tried using a combination of `JScrollPane`s and `JPanel`s with `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` as well as calls to `setPreferedSize` and `setMinimumSize` to no success.  I feel that setting this sort of gui up should be fairly straightforward but can't seem to figure out a solution.

Comment: `I've tried using a combination of JScrollPanes and JPanels with GridLayout and GridBagLayout as well as calls to setPreferedSize and setMinimumSize to no success.` - Don't use calls to `setPreferredSize()`. This will prevent scrolling from working!!! Just add the child panels to your parent panel and create the JScrollPane using the parent panel and then add the scrollPane to the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use JPanels, then the JPanel that is held by the viewport should override the JPanel class and should implement the Scrollable interface, returning proper values for the overridden methods, especially the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` method. For my money though, I'd prefer to use a JList and use appropriate renderers instead of JPanels, and then setting my JLists visibleRowCount via its `setVisibleRowCount(...)`  method.

For example:

**Example edited to now show both JList and a Scrollable JPanel**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class VisibleRows extends JPanel {
    private DefaultListModel<Datum> dataModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Datum> datumList = new JList<>(dataModel);

    public VisibleRows() {
        DataPanel dataPanel = new DataPanel(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            String name = "John Smith " + i;
            int value = i;
            Datum datum = new Datum(name, value);
            dataPanel.addDatum(datum);
            dataModel.addElement(datum);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(dataPanel);
        scrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scrollPane1);

        datumList.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        datumList.setCellRenderer(new DatumRenderer());
        datumList.setPrototypeCellValue(new Datum("XXXXXXXXXXX", 200));
        JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(datumList);
        scrollPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scrollPane2);

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("VisibleRows");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new VisibleRows());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DatumRenderer extends DatumPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Datum> {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Datum> list, Datum value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setDatum(value);
        return this;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DataPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {
    private int visibleRowCount = 1;

    public DataPanel(int visibleRowCount) {
        this.visibleRowCount = visibleRowCount;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    }

    public void addDatum(Datum datum) {
        add(new DatumPanel(datum));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        if (getComponentCount() > 0) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent) getComponents()[0];
            int width = getPreferredSize().width;
            int height = visibleRowCount * comp.getPreferredSize().height;
            Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
            System.out.println(d);
            return d;
        } else {
            return new Dimension(0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        if (getComponentCount() > 0) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent) getComponents()[0];
            Dimension d = comp.getPreferredSize();
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.VERTICAL) {
                return d.height;
            } else {
                return d.width;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        if (getComponentCount() > 0) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent) getComponents()[0];
            Dimension d = comp.getPreferredSize();
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.VERTICAL) {
                return visibleRowCount * d.height;
            } else {
                return d.width;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DatumPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GBC_I = 3;
    private Datum datum;
    private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel valueLabel = new JLabel();

    public DatumPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Name:"), createGbc(0, 0));
        add(nameLabel, createGbc(1, 0));
        add(new JLabel("Value:"), createGbc(0, 1));
        add(valueLabel, createGbc(1, 1));
    }

    public DatumPanel(Datum datum) {
        this();
        setDatum(datum);
    }

    public final void setDatum(Datum datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
        nameLabel.setText(datum.getName());
        valueLabel.setText("" + datum.getValue());
    }

    public Datum getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GBC_I, GBC_I, GBC_I, GBC_I);
        gbc.insets.left = x != 0 ? 3 * GBC_I : GBC_I;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }
}

class Datum {
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public Datum(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Name: " + name + "\n");
        sb.append("Value: " + value);
        return super.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonsInScrollPane{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p.add(getJButton(p));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(p);
        frame.setContentPane(scroll);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static public JButton getJButton(JPanel p){
        JButton b = new JButton("more");
        b.addActionListener(evt->{
            p.add(getJButton(p));
            p.revalidate();
            p.repaint();
            });
        return b;
    }
}
```

Click the button a few times, it will have too many buttons, then it will activate the scroll. It should be nearly exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: You just need to revalidate() and repaint() the panel after adding/removing a component from the panel.